# SortedDictionary with class for a key becomes unsorted

Tags: c#, sorteddictionary

SortedDictionary is supposed to always be sorted by its key.

Now consider the following code:

```
public class ContentKey
{
    public int key_num = 0;
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ContentKey a = new ContentKey() {key_num = 10};
    ContentKey b = new ContentKey() {key_num = 20};
    ContentKey c = new ContentKey() {key_num = 30};
    
    SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string> dict = new SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string>(new KeyComparer());
    dict.Add(a, "A");
    dict.Add(c, "C");
    dict.Add(b, "B");
    
    foreach(var key_value in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key val: " + key_value.Key.key_num + " Str: " + key_value.Value);
    }

    a.key_num = 50;
    
    foreach(var key_value in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key val: " + key_value.Key.key_num + " Str: " + key_value.Value);
    }
}
                                     
public class KeyComparer : IComparer<ContentKey>
{
    public int Compare(ContentKey a, ContentKey b)
    {
        return a.key_num.CompareTo(b.key_num);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8wwK8P

I would expect it to print: *A, B, C* for the first batch and then *B, C, A*.
However it's *A,B,C* in both cases.
This means the dictionary has not "realized" that the state of the key has in fact changed.

How can this be solved (without removing and reinserting A, since in practice I may not know which of many keys has changed)?

Comment: You should not use a mutable key for dictionaries

Comment: @DanielA.White Well.. what data structure would you suggest then when my usecase requires complex, mutable objects as keys?

Comment: @DragonGamer: No efficient dictionary is just going to magically know that the property it relies on has stopped applying. You need to keep track of things well enough to be able to remove and reinsert.

Comment: @Ry- I do know when a change has happened, so a data structure that gives me a "Sort" method would be sufficient. Guess I'll have to build my own, based on a List of key-value pairs and apply Sort to that one when needed.

Comment: That will be massively slower than removing and reinserting only changed keys, proportional to the length of your list.

Comment: Resorting the entire collection is going to be a lot more work than just removing and adding a new item.

Comment: Guess one solution then could be (in the example) to add a bool state like "dirty" which is set whenever a relevant member is changed, and then loop through all "keys" and reinsert the ones that are dirty. Or alternatively keep track of dirty keys in a separate list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you're going about things wrong here. A list or an array would be more appropriate but here's the solution to your problem. You can remove the stuff related to the Boolean value if you'd like, that's only there for your benefit of tracking the values.

```
public class ContentKey
{
    private int _key_num = 0;
    public bool keyChanged = false;

    public ContentKey(int keynum = 0)
    {
      _key_num = keynum;
    }
    
    public int key_num
    {
        get { return _key_num; }
        set
        {
            if (_key_num != value)
            {
                _key_num = value;
                keyChanged = true;
            }
        }
    }
}


public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ContentKey a = new ContentKey(10);
    ContentKey b = new ContentKey(20);
    ContentKey c = new ContentKey(30);

    SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string> dict = new SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string>(new KeyComparer());
    dict.Add(a, "A");
    dict.Add(c, "C");
    dict.Add(b, "B");

    foreach (var key_value in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key val: " + key_value.Key.key_num + " Key Changed: " + key_value.Key.keyChanged + " Str: " + key_value.Value);
    }

    a.key_num = 50;
    ReSortDict(ref dict);

    foreach (var key_value in dict)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Key val: " + key_value.Key.key_num + " Key Changed: " + key_value.Key.keyChanged + " Str: " + key_value.Value);
    }
}

public class KeyComparer : IComparer<ContentKey>
{
    public int Compare(ContentKey a, ContentKey b)
    {
        return a.key_num.CompareTo(b.key_num);
    }
}

public static void ReSortDict(ref SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string> dict)
{
  SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string> tempDict = new SortedDictionary<ContentKey, string>(new KeyComparer());
  foreach(var key_value in dict)
  {
    tempDict.Add(key_value.Key,key_value.Value);
  }
  dict = tempDict;
}
```

What this code does is it reads in the dictionary by reference and adds them to a sorted dictionary same as you did earlier in your code, it then overrides the dictionary object with the new values sorted.

Comment: Did end up using a list indeed and do the sorting "on demand" when reading it, instead of when the sort-condition changed (which would have been the hassle I tried to avoid). The computation load isn't as evenly spread as hoped, but I can live with it. Your solution is interesting though if somebody really needs the dict. It would unfortunately be everything but performant due to recreating the whole dict structure on every change...
Coming to think of it, I should have made it more clear in my question why I have these constraints and intentions.